# Ruby loop and code functionality

Tags: ruby

Here is the original question [euler project 50](https://projecteuler.net/problem=50)
   As question states "The longest sum of consecutive primes below one-thousand that adds to a prime, contains 21 terms"

So I start finding the answer after 21 terms as

> next if !arr[i..i+d+c].reduce(:+).prime?

The problem is at

> break if !arr[i..i+d+c].reduce(:+).prime?

I want to get out of the while loop as quickly as possible if there is no consecutive primes added to prime. It turns out there is no consecutive primes to prime in the range and counter the my logic. please enlighten me.

```
 require 'mathn'

def consecutive_prime_sum
    arr = []

    Prime.each do |i|
        break if i > 1000000
        arr << i
    end 


    max,sum = 0,0
    d = 20
    arr.each_index do |i|   
        c = 1
        next if !arr[i..i+d+c].reduce(:+).prime?

        while i+d+c <= arr.size - 1
            break if !arr[i..i+d+c].reduce(:+).prime?

            if c > max && arr[i..i+d+c].reduce(:+) > sum && arr[i..i+d+c].reduce(:+).prime?
                max = c 
                sum = arr[i..i+d+c].reduce(:+)
            end 

        c= c + 1    
        end     
    end 

    sum

end 


p consecutive_prime_sum
```

Comment: How can the array of consecutive primes both be the longest and has 21 terms?

Comment: @CarySwoveland the longest term is 21 when the prime is less than 1000, and the question is asking for the longest consecutive primes of sum which has to be prime under 1 million, so I believe the consecutive primes term should be larger than 21 terms!  That's why my range starting with plus 20 to eliminate the term less than 21.